# Difficult Regexp

Tags: regex

I need a regexp which does the following:
Heres the name of an HTML input field:

```
lm[0][ti]
```

I need to find the basic name ("lm"). Only *if* the name contains brackets I need to find the string in the second brackets ("ti").

To get it in portions is easy with the following regexp:

```
([a-zA-Z\d_]+)\[?([0-9]*)\]?\[?([a-zA_Z\d_]+)\]?
```

It matches all the portions I need.

```
Array
(
    [0] => lm[0][ti]
    [1] => lm
    [2] => 0
    [3] => ti
)
```

But if the HTML input name was just "lm", using this regexp I cannot determine that item #4 in the array is a valid name. The array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lm
    [1] => l
    [2] => 
    [3] => m
)
```

"m" is not valid for me, I'd like to get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lm
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

or this

```
Array
(
    [0] => lm
)
```

You can test the regexp here:
http://regexp-tester.mediacix.de/exp/regex/

Thanks for support in finding the right regexp...

Comment: Are you saying that it should match if 'lm' stood alone, with nothing else? Also if it was other letters? Is this writting in a name attribute? name='lm[0][ti]'?

Comment: Yes, it should match only name="lm" as well as name="lm[0][ti]"... The regexp below does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\w+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?(?:\[(\w+)\])?
```

Input:

```
lm[0][ti]
```

Output:

[image]

Input:

```
lm
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Cool! Works! +1 for utmost answering speed! Thanks!

Comment: @Kirill Which tool you have used?

Comment: @Hein, Thanks. In SO you can say "thanks" upvoting or marking post as answer :-)

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk - Voted ;-)